# Pass variable from twig to js

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, variables, twig

Is there some way to pass variables from twig to javascript file that lay in public/js directory of bundle. Or do I need to assign my variables in template and then include my script file where vars will be used?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assign the variable in the template and pick it up with javascript...

```
<script>
var foo = '{{ foo }}';
alert(foo);
</script>
```

Answer (score 31):

Another way without having to have your javascript file as a template would be to have the javascript value as a `data-*` attribute and then get that from your javascript file. This would mean that your javascript wouldn't necessarily be coupled to your twig file.

```
<a href="#" data-id="{{ entity.id }}" id="some-link">Link</a>
```

With jQuery..

```
var id = $('#some-link').data('id');
```

With regular javascript (i think)..

```
var id = document.querySelector('#some-link').dataset.id;
```

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted one IMO because you don't need to insert js in twig template.

Answer (score 3):

watch this

```
variable in twig:    fpoint = [{'id': 1},{'id': 2}]
```

if it is an array

```
var fg = $.parseJSON('{{ fpoint | json_encode | raw }}');
for(k in fg){
  console.log("fpoint: ", fg[k].id);
}
```

Comment: Once the initial knee-jerk reaction of "gods this is horrible" is passed, serializing to JSON and back is probably the least bad way of passing actual data structures instead of just strings in parsed javascript templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your twig

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var settings = {
        example: {{ 'something' | trans }}
        }
    };
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

then you can access them in your js:

```
console.log(settings.example);
```