# Assign an object variable from Twig to javascript

Tags: javascript, twig

Using this syntax (according to [Pass variable from twig to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381591/pass-variable-from-twig-to-js)):

```
var channelData={{ ChannelDataFeed }};
```

was rendered as a descriptive string of the object (which then caused an error in the js since I didn't use quotes).
I don't want to copy each attribute from the Twig variable since it's tedious, so I'm looking for a way to assign the variable as a whole.
Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: You will need either to use quotes or to assign that twig variable to a data-attribute in the html then retrieve it.

Comment: `var data = {{ data | ` [json_encode](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html) `}};`

Comment: It's rendered as an empty object. Is it because all its attributes are protected? (they have public getters)

Comment: [Specify data which should be serialized to JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)