# Access Twig Variable in OctoberCMS Javascript file

Tags: javascript, twig, octobercms

I am Using OctoberCMS which is based in Laravel Framework and I set variable in my html file 
`{% set name = 'Juan' %}` 
and i am trying to access it in my Javascript file by setting variable like this 
`var myName = '{{ name }}'` 
and i alert the variable `myName` but unfortunately it doesn't display the variable `myName` instead it displayed the whole string like this {{ name }}

Comment: you should put the js code in a Twig file otherwise is not processed by the twig engine

Comment: but OctoberCMS has already implemented Twig as their templating engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig variable in extern js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604063/twig-variable-in-extern-js-file)

Comment: @JOHNJASONMIGUEL please see my answer below if that is what you need.

Comment: I am using OctoberCMS not Symfony.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are hinting at John. `Twig` is `twig` whether it is used inside october, symfony, silex or standalone... External `JS` files are not getting through the `twig` compiler thus either define the variables you need directly inside your template or assign them to a data attrtibute of a container

Comment: @DarkBee you are correct but i am thinking if there is another way to do it like Blade templating Engine in Laravel PHP Framework.

Comment: The only other way i've seen is to rewrite (like with `mod_rewrite`) your `JS` file to a `PHP` one which then is able to set the header of the content type to `javascript` and has access to `twig` or anything you want, but do note this create a whole new request, not giving you access to some details of the request which called the javascript. This question has been asked many times and the same answers always pop-up. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381591/pass-variable-from-twig-to-js) for instance

Comment: You could also have a look at [FOS JsRouting](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are defining whole thing in `javascript`

So, template engine has no clue what you want, what I suggest is just define variables in Html like this

so previously you did this.

```
{% set name = 'Juan' %}
```

so now to pass this `variable to js` you can do something like this for simplicity. [its unprofessional and I do not suggest it instead we can use our namespace/object and pass it]

```
<script>var myName = '{{ name }}';</script>
```

> make sure this line is not written in `js` file it must be in one of `.htm` `layout/template` or in `markup section`.

then throughout in your project inside js you can access it.

```
alert(myName);
```

and if it do not seems relevant to you then we suggest you to post laravel code which can do stuff like this so we give better working relevant solution.

if you find any doubts please comment.

Answer (score 0):

well javascript file does not support twig templating engine so it will not understand
what is 
 **{{ name }}** variable.

but you can do a workaround over here like that

in your .htm twig file you can print the variable in a span and make it display:none

```
<span id="name" style="display: none;">{{ name }}</span>
```

and then call it into your js file like this

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML
```

or if you jave jquery included then you can do like this

```
var name = $("#name").val()
```

I hope this help

Comment: Sorry this answer is not relevant, I asked this question because in the OctoberCMS documentation there is nothing about this. unlike in Laravel Framework using Blade Templating Engine you can do `{{ route('profile') }}` hope OctoberCMS developer can notice this.