# use twig variable in JS

Tags: javascript, twig

(Hey!)
I try to use a twig variable in my JS file, I tried the way mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381591/pass-variable-from-twig-to-js) but in my case, it doesn't works.

```
{% for property_name, property_rent in property %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ property_name }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ property_rent }} €
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

and this JS :

```
let property = "{{ property }}";
console.log(property);
```

return {{ property }} instead of an array

Of course I tried with simple and double quotes. Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
let property = {{ property }}
```

**Update**

Let's try a [Symfony way](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/server-data.html) :

Twig :

```
<div class="js-user" data-user="{{ app.user }}">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var userBlock = document.querySelector('.js-user');
    var user = userBlock.dataset.user;

    // or with jQuery
    //var user = $('.js-user').data('user');
});
```

Comment: yes I tried :/ I'm using webpack encore, so the JS file in included in the html file ```<script src="/build/monthResumeGraph.js"></script>```

Answer (score 0):

you should have a toArray function into your variable and call :

```
app_user = {{ app.user.toArray|json_encode() }};
```