# Filling a select2 with given send to javascript

Tags: twig, jquery-select2

On an application I created a form with a field (select) in EntityType, I then passed it to select2, no problem there.

The twig view looks like an array of all saved helpers and you can modify a helper by opening a modal, I correctly pass my value twig to js with dataset and all the fields are filled in correctly.

To better have a little visual, my button that opens my modal and sends it all the info looks like this :

```
    <a href="javascript:;" class="menu-link px-3" {{ stimulus_action('deal--handle', 'editHelp') }} data-url2="{{ path('help_request_edit', {'id':help.id}) }}" data-organisme="{{ help.organization.value }}" data-date="{{ help.date|date('Y-m-d') }}" data-state="{{ help.state }}" data-amount-requested="{{ help.amountRequested }}" data-amount-to-deduct="{{ help.amountToDeduct }}" data-subrogation="{{ help.subrogation }}" data-quotations="{{ quotationInHelp|json_encode }}">
       Modify
    </a>
```

`data-quotations="{{ quotationInHelp|json_encode }}"` send the data to js and I get it like this:

```
var quotations = JSON.parse(event.currentTarget.dataset.quotations);
```

in my console.log(quotations) everything is ok.

but I can't find how to use the data of my "quotations" variable to pass them into values ​​of my select2, for example the other fields of my modal are filled like this:

```
        this.subrogationTarget.value = event.currentTarget.dataset.subrogation;
```

if you have any ideas/solutions for this problem, thank you!

Comment: The filter `json_encode` doesn't mark the output as safe, as seen [here](https://twigfiddle.com/y4i8zm). You need to add the filter  `raw` as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass variable from twig to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381591/pass-variable-from-twig-to-js)

Comment: It does not work because my button to edit the modal is specific to an element.the entity that I have to display in the select2 is finally a ManyToMany relationship.
`#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Quotation::class, inversedBy: 'helpRequests')]
    private Collection $quotations;`
` {% set quotationInHelp = [] %}
 quotationsInHelp contains an array of my entity(ies) linked to a helpRequest
and it is this "quotationsInHelp" that I want to pass to js, ​​an array with one/several entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution with a few lines of javascript

```
var quotations = JSON.parse(event.currentTarget.dataset.quotations);
var i = 0;
    var idQuotations = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < quotations.length; ++i) {
        idQuotations.push(
            quotations[i]['quotation']
        );
    }
    $(this.quotationTarget).val(idQuotations).trigger("change");
```